# taylor series (ln,arctan,...) in python

Tags: python, taylor-series

I need a program for arctan(x) with plot in python

```
def Arctan(X:float,n:int=10):
    s=0
    for i in range(n):
        flag=(-1)**i 
        series=(X**((2*i)+1))/2*i+1
        s=s+flag*series
        return s
```

this always return 1

Comment: return should be placed outide for loop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and think carefully about the logic of the code. In particular: where the code says `return s`, exactly what do you think this means? When should it happen: after all of the loop results are added to `s`, or at the end of each loop? Therefore, should this code be inside the loop, or outside? Is it?

Comment: Also: please *carefully check* what each step of the code does. Make sure you *understand what to expect* at each step, and then *see where* it goes wrong. This is the fundamental technique of *debugging*, and we do not do it for others here. Stack Overflow is for **after** you find the problem, in case you need to *understand* what you found.

Comment: `/2*i+1` --> `/(2*i+1)` and check the `return`'s position